# Unexpected usage of event in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I want to write simple form with create-react-app but i can't because event i can't use event object. The error that i get is 
./src/components/Form.js
  Line 14:  Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals

It is a problem with newest create-react-app. The code is from react docs.

```
import React from 'react';

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Line 14 `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 2):

Your handleSubmit function should be changed as follows

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: I had a problem with vim. Vim didnt want to save. After the changes i have now error 
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Comment: @KamilStaszewski Can you show us how your new error looks like. Also did my answer solve the ` Unexpected use of 'event' no-restricted-globals` error ?